# How to find any resources appropriate for the specified culture

Tags: c#, dll, reference, assemblies

I have got one project from my anther branch.while running that project i am getting below error:

could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutrla culture. Make sure  "Manufacturing.Images.resources"Was correcly embedded or linked into assembly "QBSBM" at compile time. or that all the satellite assemblys required are loadable and fully singed.

Actually i dont have Images folder under Manufaturing project. But in the error message it is showing.
Can you suggestion me how can i solve this reference error.